# calling html template in block

Tags: magento2, blocks, template

my 1column.xml file

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header slide" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

here i want insert my custom html inside header.container

so all i did was inside my `frontend/{mypachage}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/custom-header.phtml` now i want to inject `header.phtml` inside header tag so inside  my `theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`  i edited and added  line

```
<referenceContainer name="header_container"> 
  <block  type="page/html" name="asd" template="html/header.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

But nothing happens

Comment: Did you try with `<referenceContainer name="header.container">` ?

Comment: oh yes i tried both with name and as of original container and do i have to create class to use templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to try with below code,
in magento 2 block with `type attribute` are **removed** you have to use with `class attribute`.

```
<referenceContainer name="header_container"> 
     <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.header" template="Magento_Theme::html/custom-header.phtml">
</referenceContainer>
```

Clear cache and check again.

Comment: yes this works but what does class do?

Comment: class takes full path of your block class. you can check above class path from vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php

Comment: but my file path was inside my own dir

Comment: you have to just give path like this , Vendor/Module/Block/Custom

Comment: your class doesnot work but class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" works

Comment: yes you have to set your own class , i have just reference to you. above class is for only demo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39060/discussion-between-ujwal-dhakal-and-rakesh).